# Overcast Podcast - how to automatically play next podcast in a playlist?

Tags: podcasts, podcasts.app

The Overcast podcast app (from Marco Arment) used to play all podcasts in a playlist sequentially. Now, the player stops after each podcast. How can I go back to previous behavior?

Edit: This is on an iPhone6

Comment: I'm using v2.5.7 and it plays the next episode in all the playlists I have.  Have you tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling?  Maybe a plist or property file was corrupted somehow.

Comment: Just updated both my iOS and the Overcast and it's still not working.

Comment: Check in Overcast's 'Settings -> Nitpicky Details' and make sure 'Play Next By Priority' is set to Off. That's the only other thing I can think of because my app works fine.

Comment: Yes, it's off. I wonder if it's an iPhone thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start playing a podcast and once it's playing, click on PLAYBACK in the lower left corner.  That will give you the option to play next or stop.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is having this issue, you might have 'Play Next by Priority' turned on.

I was finding that after an episode ended, the next episode that started playing was the one at the top of the playlist.

Toggling this to 'off' will ensure that the next episode on the list will be played, and not the topmost episode.

[image]

Comment: In v2022.3 this is reversed as the “Stop After Each Episode” toggle.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the podcast, click "All" in the center, and then in the top right click "All..." which brings up the option to "Add # Episodes," and after clicking "Add # Episodes" the continuous play function works as expected.